# How to use Haskell data type created?

Tags: haskell

I am new programming in Haskell. I'm trying to print my new data type but doesn't work. Im doing this in Geany, making a main.

```
module Main (
main
) where

import Graphics.UI.Gtk
--import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.IORef


--main::IO ()
main = do
 pila <- newIORef (Pila[])

 let x = apilar 1 pila
 putStrLn x

 mainGUI


-------------------------


data Pila x = Pila[x] deriving (Show)

pila_vacia :: Pila x
pila_vacia = Pila[]

apilar :: x -> Pila x -> Pila x
apilar e (Pila lista) = Pila([e] ++ lista)
```

Error from terminal: Maybe something wrong with arguments

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main( Pilas.hs, Pilas.o )

Pilas.hs:14:19:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Pila x’
                with actual type ‘IORef (Pila x0)’
    Relevant bindings include
      x :: Pila x (bound at Pilas.hs:14:6)
      pila :: IORef (Pila x0) (bound at Pilas.hs:12:2)
    In the second argument of ‘apilar’, namely ‘pila’
    In the expression: apilar 1 pila

Pilas.hs:15:11:
    Couldn't match type ‘Pila x1’ with ‘[Char]’
    Expected type: String
      Actual type: Pila x1
    In the first argument of ‘putStrLn’, namely ‘x’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: putStrLn x
```

Sorry my bad english

Comment: Do you get any error messages? If so, please include them in the question.

Comment: Of course, sorry.

Comment: [1 of 1] Compiling Main ( Pilas.hs, Pilas.o )
Pilas.hs:14:19:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Pila x’
                with actual type ‘IORef (Pila x0)’
    Relevant bindings include
      x :: Pila x (bound at Pilas.hs:14:6)
      pila :: IORef (Pila x0) (bound at Pilas.hs:12:2)
    In the second argument of ‘apilar’, namely ‘pila’
    In the expression: apilar 1 pila

Pilas.hs:15:11:
    Couldn't match type ‘Pila x1’ with ‘[Char]’
    Expected type: String
      Actual type: Pila x1
    In the first argument of ‘putStrLn’, namely ‘x’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: putStrLn x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `pila` is not of type `Pila x`, as you apparently expect, but of type `IORef (Pila x)`. That's what [the function `newIORef`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-11.5/base-4.10.1.0/Data-IORef.html#v:newIORef) does - it creates a new `IORef`.

In order to get the `Pila` value out of the `IORef`, use [the `readIORef` function](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-11.5/base-4.10.1.0/Data-IORef.html#v:readIORef), like this:

```
main = do 
    pilaRef <- newIORef (Pila[]) 

    pila <- readIORef pilaRef
    let x = apilar 1 pila 
    ...
```

Comment: Seems im given a 'Pila Integer' instead String
Pilas.hs:16:11:
    Couldn't match type ‘Pila Integer’ with ‘[Char]’
    Expected type: String
      Actual type: Pila Integer
    In the first argument of ‘putStrLn’, namely ‘x’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: putStrLn x

Comment: @GozarD: You want `print x`, which is equivalent to `putStrLn (show x)`. The `Show` instance for `Pila` is created for you by the `deriving (Show)` on `data Pila`. Also, you can use `modifyIORef' pila (apilar 1)` instead of `readIORef` followed by `writeIORef`. (`modifyIORef` without a prime `'` is lazy, so it may cause performance problems if you’re repeatedly modifying the `IORef`, so I suggest `modifyIORef'` until you have a solid understanding of laziness.)